# Графики highcharts проблема при сужении экрана увеличивается размер сетки

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Добрый день

Использую библиотеку для построения графиков Highcharts.
возникла проблема что при сужении экрана почему то размер сетки увеличивается , подскажите как это отключить или исправить ?

к примеру нормальное отображение http://prntscr.com/h6u3bp  и с увеличенным размером сетки http://prntscr.com/h6u3vc
как я понимаю тут срабатывает увеличение но перепробовал все варианты с zoom ничего не подходит

Answer (score 0):

решил вопрос , обернул в теги   и указал максимальную ширину таблицы